# Selenium Firefox span tag

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm having a problem with selecting an element by linkText which is located in a span. In Chrome it works perfectly but in Firefox it doesn't for some reason and i can't understand it for hours already. I'm trying to locate the element as follows: `login.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Kassa"))).click();` However it simply doesn't find it. I noticed that all other elements that are located in the upper navigation bar and the text isn't in a span tag it finds easley, however thous that are in the span it can't find. What is the difference and what is the best way to reach to that element. Because in this case finding by linkText seems to be perfect. Thank you! HTML attached:

```
<nav class="site-navbar navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bg-teal-600" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-brand site-gridmenu-toggle" data-toggle="gridmenu">
                    <span class="navbar-brand-text">whatever</span>
                </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hamburger hamburger-close collapsed" data-target="#site-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <i class="hamburger-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-avatar navbar-toggle padding-horizontal-0" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false" data-animation="scale-up" role="button">
                <span class="avatar avatar-online" style="top: -3px">
                    <img src="https://whatever.png" alt="...">                  <i></i>
                </span>
            </button>

                         <a type="button" href="https://whatever" class="navbar-toggle padding-top-15 padding-horizontal-0">
                <span class="btn btn-warning"> Kassa </span>
            </a>
```

Code snippet: 
`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Then i'm going to the webpage, through basic authentication , won't post this data here and basically on the page that i land i want to try to find the element like that:

```
login.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Kassa"))).click();
```

Picture of the nav. bar [nav. bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8NgT.png)

Comment: can you add the code snippet?

Comment: @bad_deadpool I added, hope it's enough let me know if you need any other information, but there nothing complex about it, just one method that i use to try to locate one element. But most important thing is that it works perfectly in Chrome, which means the code is okay for sure. I'm using Selenium 3.4, GeckoDriver 0.16 and Firefox 53.0, i tried downgrading one version of Firefox, same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although if a certain code works on chrome it should work on firefox as well; but if it isn't working then you can try to find the said element using following :

**UPDATED:**

```
 WebElement navElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.container-fluid a>span.btn.btn-warning"));

 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(navElement).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly it doesn't work. That's the problem that more or less i'm confident that everything is set up correctly, driver e.t.c because it does open the browser, goes to the page and it can work with some elements, for example thous that have a text not in the span, besides it really works perfectly in Chrome. But this element for example, is not possible to reach except brute xpath which i consider not really good. I'm really out of options. I'm using Selenium v3.4, GeckoDriver v0.16 and Firefox v53

Comment: Also this is a navigation bar, right?? so you have to hover/click on the options to get to the <span>

Comment: No error , just the following timeout exception : `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: div.container-fluid a>span.btn.btn-warning (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)` About the hover/click i'll attach a picture from the web page of the nav. bar. All i need is to click that element and i would like to point out once more that it works perfectly with Chrome.

Comment: Yeah it does work like that! That's great, but could you please explain me briefly what's going on or is the gecko version simply broken ?

Comment: That can't be said for sure; but using actions class first we are changing the focus to that particular element and then interacting with it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But one last, small question, is it a good practice to make different classes to test other browsers? And once more thank you for all the support.

Comment: No it's not a good practice to make different classes to test on different browser; code should be same for all the browsers

Comment: Thanks to your help i just found out that the problem is in the class wait most likely. It can find the element if u use directly findElement, but if i use ExpectedConditions.(and any other method here) it doesn't find it even though the method is correctly 100%. Now i'm totally confused.